# How can I download and name the downloaded file using loop in cypress?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, automation, cypress

```
describe('download',function()
{
it('fils',function()
{
  
cy.visit('url')
cy.get('.ds_class_data_sheet').click()
cy.wait(3000)
const numberoftest=68;
for (let i = 1; i <= numberoftest; i ++) {    
  
cy.get('.dsDocumentData > .dsTitle > .dsDocumentLink').eq(i).then(function(e1)
{
  const url=e1.prop('href')
  
  cy.downloadFile(url,'cypress/downloads/Datasheet','file1.pdf')
  
}

)
}

  

}



)
})
```

I tried by writing the code like this. There happen the downloads but my question is how do I name the downloaded file using the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the name inside the loop, use a string template.

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= numberoftest; i ++) {    
  cy.get('.dsDocumentData > .dsTitle > .dsDocumentLink').eq(i)
    .then(function(e1) {
      const url = e1.prop('href')

      // name whatever format desired, maybe last part of url
      const id = url.split('/')[3]
      const name = `file_${id}`      

      cy.downloadFile(url,'cypress/downloads/Datasheet', name)
    })
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cypress comes with [lodash](https://describe(%27download%27,function()%20%7B%20it(%27fils%27,function()%20%7B%20%20%20%20cy.visit(%27url%27)%20cy.get(%27.ds_class_data_sheet%27).click()%20cy.wait(3000)%20const%20numberoftest=68;%20for%20(let%20i%20=%201;%20i%20%3C=%20numberoftest;%20i%20++)%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20cy.get(%27.dsDocumentData%20%3E%20.dsTitle%20%3E%20.dsDocumentLink%27).eq(i).then(function(e1)%20%7B%20%20%20const%20url=e1.prop(%27href%27)%20%20%20%20%20%20cy.downloadFile(url,%27cypress/downloads/Datasheet%27,%27file1.pdf%27)%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20)%20%7D%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20)%20%7D)) so you can use _.times(n, function()).

```js
describe('download',() => {
 it('fils',() => { 
  cy.visit('url')
  cy.get('.ds_class_data_sheet').click()
  cy.wait(3000)
  const numberoftest=68;
  Cypress._.times(numberoftest, (i) => {
   cy.get('.dsDocumentData > .dsTitle > .dsDocumentLink')
     .eq(i)
     .then(e1 => {
      const url=e1.prop('href')
      cy.downloadFile(url,'cypress/downloads/Datasheet','file1.pdf')
   })
 })
})
```